# Azure function not found after publishing using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm testing Azure Functions for the first time using VS 2019 and this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio

When I run the function locally, everything works fine. Then the guide tells me to use VS to publish the app to my Azure account, which I do successfully, and I see a newly created function app in the Azure website:

[image]

But if I try to call the function using

```
https://functionapp220200104024331.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1
```

as I'm supposed to, I get a 404 error.

If I look at "Functions" at the Azure portal, I see none:

[image]

and I think I should see "Function1" there, but it is not listed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: did it get publish successfuly?

Comment: Function deploy failed. You still can see the plus sign.

Comment: Hi, rettiseert. Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the functions got **created** successfully, bit did not get **published**.

The publish flow in Visual Studio first enables you to *create* a Function App to publish to, but it's only the last 'Publish' step that actually *deploys* something to Azure. Are you sure you clicked the button labelled 'Publish'?

You can open the 'Web Publish Activity' or 'Microsoft Azure Activity Log' Window under *View > Other Windows* which should give you some more information on if the publish happened.

You can go to https://functionapp220200104024331.scm.azurewebsites.net (it runs [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu)) to get some more insight into what is and what isn't available.

Answer (score -3):

First, as rickvdbosch says, maybe you don't click the publish button. The Visual Studio create the app service on Azure and wait for you to publish.

Second, Given that the function is not shown under your functionapp, I think this may be a deployment failure. That means you publish to azure but the function is not publish successful. If your function app is created by local. It will publish dll file and the function app will be 'readonly'.

This is your functionapp, you can see there is a plus sign here:

[image]

But if you deploy  successfully, your function app will be like this:

[image]

(Without a plus sign and cannot be edited.)

So I think there is no function under your function app.

**You can take the following steps to test my judgment:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you deploy successful, you will find your function here, a .dll file. But as your description, I think you deploy failed.